# Designing ListViewItems (Selection Color) is not working at all

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I want to design the selection colors of my ListViewItems individually. I found a **lot of how-tos** to this.

But somehow: Nothing seems to work at all.
In my current sample, I re-used the sample from that link: [How to style ListView selection?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f10c6c9c-a869-42c3-8695-0f9b04bf615b/how-to-style-listview-selection?forum=wpf)

I made it easily work for **TreeViewItems**, but neither for **ListViewItems** nor **ListBoxItems** it's working.

Can someone explain me, what I am doing wrong?
This is my xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"             
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="200" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}" Color="Red"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrush}" Color="Gray"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true" >
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" /> <!-- only foreground works -->
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}" Color="Red"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrush}" Color="Gray"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}" Color="Red"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrush}" Color="Gray"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>Item a 1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item a 2</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <ListView>
        <ListViewItem>Item b 1</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item b 2</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Node Level 0">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Node Level 1" />
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and this is how it always looks:

[image]

I also tried already all the available resource keys of SystemColors. None had any effect. This screenshot is the result of a new WpfApp, I have no global styles.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this with ListBox and ListView:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" >
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Padding="0,5,0,5" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="White" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Padding="0,5,0,5" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="White" BorderThickness="1">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>

                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>Item a 1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item a 2</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <ListView>
        <ListViewItem>Item b 1</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item b 2</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

The code produces the following result:

[image: Example]

The best source I've found for this is [on MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f10c6c9c-a869-42c3-8695-0f9b04bf615b/how-to-style-listview-selection?forum=wpf). You can find some alternative options from the discussion.

Comment: Actually I wanted to avoid modifying the Item using a template, as all my items are custom Views including backgrounds. But for the moment, It's my only possiblity. What **really** makes me insane, is the fact that everywhere it seems to work with the other solution. Ill make this as solution next week. Maby someone finds the issue.